# Angularjs - Anonymous template load cause response error in interceptor

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Would like to check, I am using AngularJS 1.4.4 with [AngularUI](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). So recently I have upgraded my site to use JWT tokens. The JWT tokens are being sent via headers in http request. So I've also added an interceptor to intercept all requests Angular made to the server like this

```
request: function(config){
    config.headers = config.headers || {};
           if ($localStorage.jwtToken) {
               config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $localStorage.jwtToken;
           }
           return config;
},
response: function(response) {
  if(response.headers('New-Jwt-Token')){
    console.log(response.headers('New-Jwt-Token'));
  }
},
responseError: function (response) {
  // handle the case where the user is not authenticated
  if (response.status === 401) {
     if(response.data.error === 'token_ttl_expired'){
      if(response.data.new_jwt_token){
        $localStorage['jwtToken'] = response.data.new_jwt_token;
        console.log('jwt updated');
      }
    }
  }
  return $q.reject(response);
}
```

What I have noticed is while angular made the requests there is also many anonymous template requests being made to routes that dont exist in my website which causes then entire program to stop working.

[image]

How should i remove / prevent / delete these unnecessary templates from loading?

**Update**: If found out this is actually cause by the AngularUI bootstrap. [image: enter image description 1][image: enter image description 2]

How should i prevent this from being intercepted by the interceptor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is more than likely caused by no `response` being returning in your `response` interceptor. So it should be:

```
response: function(response) {
  if(response.headers('New-Jwt-Token')){
    console.log(response.headers('New-Jwt-Token'));
  }
  return response;
},
```

The `request` interceptor will intercept all requests AFAIK. Note that with ui-bootstrap, the templates are cached in the `$templateCache` so no actual `GET` is actually sent to your server.

This is completely unnecessary but what you can do in your request interceptor is to do nothing if found in the `$templateCache`.

```
request: function(config){
    if (config.url && $templateCache.get(config.url)) {
        // Don't do anything
        return config;
    }

    config.headers = config.headers || {};
    if ($localStorage.jwtToken) {
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $localStorage.jwtToken;
    }
    return config;
},
```

Again, this is not necessary and doesn't achieve much but I put it here incase you have other processing logic in the `request` interceptor.